# Best way to handle resource associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I currently have a parent resource 'developments' and a child resource 'lots'.

But I need to have different types of developments now, i.e. apartments, houses, townhouses that still associate with their own lots. These different types of developments need to have different fields on their forms.

What is the simplest and easiest way to handle this?

I've currently thought of these approaches:

- add a new column `dev_type_id` integer to developments that is associated with a development type (i.e. 1 = apartments etc.) and then have that as a condition to render different fields of the form. The trouble with this is I don't know how to practically build it and pass through the id from the index view to the form path
- have multiple forms for development with different fields on them. I'm not sure how to set the routes for this approach and if it would work in practice
- Multiple parent resources to single child: split the development into separate scaffolds for apartment, houses etc. and have lots belong to all of them through has_and_belongs_to_many. This just seems like it might be really messy.
- Multiple parent resources to multiple children: Complete restructure so that Apartments has child Apartment_lots, Townhouses has child Townhouse_lots etc. etc. This seems like it would work as intended, but there *has* to be a simpler way, right? But I can see the benefit of being able to really customise each for the future if I need to.

Any suggestions spoken from experience, the rails way or anything is really appreciated.

Comment: This may be helpful https://medium.com/@ghl234/single-table-inheritance-in-rails-6-emulating-oop-principles-in-relational-databases-be60c84e0126

Comment: This may be a job for a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).